# Bootstrap menu not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I can't figure it out why the bootstrap menu is not showing on mobile/tablet ?
You can see live here: https://simpleeats.cratejoy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Because your `navbar-brand` is set to 100% width it's actually covering your `navbar-toggle` button, that's why when you click the toggle-button you're directed back to your index page: see image.

[image]

You can either change the z-index of your `navbar-toggle` class (`z-index: 1060;` works) or set a width for the image.

Sidenote: you'll see some adverse behavior due to the `img-responsive` class attached to the logo when you toggle the menu open, you shouldn't need this class though.

Working Demo of fixed width, centered `navbar-brand` image.

```css
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle.lefty {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: red;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
    </a>
    <!--FOR DEMO ONLY -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed lefty" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!--FOR DEMO ONLY -->
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```